# 'Who' with location answers

Tags: who

So I have a question about 'Who' usage. For the question 'Who has the best soccer team' why is it that a country can be the answer? I know that we could also say 'Which has the best soccer team' but that implies that we've been talking about it or maybe there is a list in front of us.

But I feel that the first one is used without previous information given. So just asking the question. Is it just a more informal way of asking?

Comment: Countries have people...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on which subject you are addressing. If you're asking about which has the best soccer team, you could be suggesting possible countries.